# Is there any possibilities to store JPanel object in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield, jpasswordfield

Hi i got an assignment from my team leader that to store the employee details what the user entered in the textfield whatever in that panel, after that in the other frame the admin have to check the details of each employee by calling the arraylist, that list should show the panel in cardlayout,, here my coding for employee registration.can anyone please help me

```
Registration()
{
    frm=new JFrame("Welcome to the login page");
    left=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    left.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    right=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    right.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    sp=new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,left,right);
    lb9=new JLabel("Member");
    lb9.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lb9.setForeground (Color.blue);
    lb10=new JLabel("Create an Account");
    lb10.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lb10.setForeground (Color.blue);
    lb1=new JLabel("Username");
    tf1=new JTextField(10);
    lb2=new JLabel("Password");
    tf6=new JTextField(10);
    lb3=new JLabel("First Name");
    tf2=new JTextField(10);
    lb4=new JLabel("Last Name");
    tf3=new JTextField (10);
    lb5=new JLabel("Password");
    psd2=new JPasswordField (10);
    lb6=new JLabel("Confirm password");
    psd3=new JPasswordField (10);
    lb7=new JLabel("MailID:");
    tf4=new JTextField (10);
    lb8=new JLabel("Contact No");
    tf5=new JTextField (10);
    b1=new JButton("Enter");
    b2=new JButton("Register");

}
public void launchFrame()
{


frm.setSize(450, 350);
frm.add(sp);
//sp.setLeftComponent(left);
//sp.setRightComponent(right);
left.add(lb9);
left.add(lb1);
left.add(tf1);
left.add(lb2);
left.add(tf6);
left.add(b1);


right.add(lb10);
right.add(lb3);
right.add(tf2);
right.add(lb4);
right.add(tf3);
right.add(lb5);
right.add(psd2);
psd2.setEchoChar('*');
right.add(lb6);
right.add(psd3);
psd3.setEchoChar('*');
right.add(lb7);
right.add(tf4);
right.add(lb8);
right.add(tf5);
right.add(b2);

frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You have a bad teacher. A good teacher would explain that you need to store objects in the (Array)List and that you extract infromation from GUI objects. Basic reason also suggests that if you can store n-filed objects then an example with two fields suffices. You do not need to post all your fields.

Comment: can you describe the issue you are having?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, it is possible. First try to do it by yourself(like create a List and add JPanel objects to it) and then ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

Create List object like this way

```
List<JPanel> panelList = new ArrayList<JPanel>();

// add your JPanel object like this way
panelList.add(yourPanel);

// retrieve your JPanel object from list
JPanel panel = panelList.get(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

only comment, not answer

> Is there any possibilities to store JPanel object in arraylist

1. yes is possible but for why reason,

   - because  number of this JComponents doesn't required to storing those JComponets in array,
   - JComponents aren't the same type of,
   - they are created as (local) variables,
   - they are accesible from whole JVM instance
2. is there any issue to pass value from concrete JComponent to anywhere inside current JVM (another classes)
3. iterate inside contianer (yours left and right JPanels) and inside iterating to test if (compo[i] instance of JTextComponent), then inside this condition you will get only access and to get value from JTextField and JPasswordField, rest of JComponents placed (JLabel, JButton e.g. ) in JPanel (for example) aren't instance of JTextComponent